# How to inject user secrets into AndroidManifest in Xamarin.Forms at build time?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, msbuild, app-secret

I have a Xamarin.Forms project, which contains an Android version of my app.

It has an AndroidManifest.xml file, which has to be populated with a meta-data tag containing a secret API key.

I use `dotnet user-secrets` to store that secret API key on my machine.

The thing I want to inject looks like this:

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="SECRET" />`

This needs to go into `manifest->application` node in the manifest.

How would I go about doing this?

I've tried prebuild events with a custom CLI tool written that outputs the needed tag into `Properties/AndroidManifest.xml`, but that's not correct, because that updated manifest is being picked up by my version control, which I don't want.

Another option is to output my tag into an `obj` folder which contains the final `AnroidManifest` file which will be used by the android app after build.

But how do I access that file? `PreLinkEvent` doesn't seem to work in my Xamarin.Android project.

Comment: About adding some data with meta-data tag, Manually or through code, I find one thread about [accessing metadata from AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743546/how-to-access-metadata-from-androidmanifest-xml-in-xamarin-froms)

Comment: Once you put something on AndroidManifest.xml, it's not a secret anymore (if you actually care about security)